# Ignore path with route-ui

Tags: angularjs, django, angular-ui-router

I have a django application and I am using angular with ui-route, but when I access /admin I want to access a django page not an angular one.. is it possible to do that?
Can I ignore the /admin route? And serve from server?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to specify `target="_self"` in your anchors to the admin.

For more description go to [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) and navigate to the Fallback for legacy browsers section.

Comment: But my problem is that the refered link isn't something acessible from an href, is the admin part of the application... which means this link is directly from url...

Comment: If you give target="_self" the request will be made to the server instead of looking in the angular routes.. It falls back to the legacy browser ie. sends request to the server.

Comment: I don't have a `<a href="/admin">` to put the `target="_self"` in, I need to ignore the url requested directly on browser...